# Find the students in batch who have all the subjects passed comparing the keywords

Tags: algorithm, c#-4.0

The question goes like this. There are 5 students grouped as batch. Each students in a batch should have passed in atleast one of the 5 subjects. The 5 subjects are physics(p), chemistry(c), botony(b), maths(m),and zoology(z). we need to find the batch of students who have passed in these.

So there could be a batch like

```
batch-1
pcmbz 

batch2
pccmb (not one student passed in zoology)

batch3
zmbcc (not one student passed in physics)

etc...
```

so if the user gives input like pcmbzpczbmpccmb. There are 3 batches out of which 2 batches have cleared atleast one subject of the 5 subjects.

My code :

```
static int team(string skills)
     {
         char[] subjects = { 'p', 'c', 'm', 'b', 'z' };
         int count = 0;
         int p = 0, c = 0, m = 0, b = 0, z = 0;
         int divisor = 0;
         char[] result = skills.ToCharArray();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

         //parse the string to 5 chars each representing the 5 students subject.

         for (int l = 0; l < skills.Length; l++)
         {
             if (l % 5 == 0 && l > 0)
             {
                 sb.Append(" ");
             }
             sb.Append(skills[l]);
         }


         string format = sb.ToString();
         char space = ' ';
         string[] resultarray = format.Split(space);


         for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.Length; i++)
         {
             if (resultarray[i].Contains("pcmbz"))
             {
                 count = count + 1;
             }
         }

         return count;
     }
```

However when I use contains, it matches for the exact word and does not recognize the jumbled one. Here `pcmbz` and `pczbm` are same.

Should i again for the logic of anagrams in the code and then check if it same then add it to the count or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Is it your homework? Why don't you check a batch that contains 'p' and contains 'c' and .. so on?

Comment: yes, i can check each individual char and loop through. if the 5 subjects extends to say 10 again i have to check individually, so i was looking for some optimized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I have to say that I'm by far **not an experienced C# programmer**. That being said I'm even certain that my solution isn't the one with the best performance but it gets the job done if I understand your problem correctly.

Checking for anagrams like you've suggested would also be possible but in case you'd want to change your subjects in future you'd have to change every single anagram string. What we want to do is to check whether every subject character exists in the given string.

Here's how I'd do the last for-loop in your code (everything else remains the way you've done it):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.Length; i++)
    {
        bool containsAllSubjects = true;
        foreach(char sub in subjects)
        {
            if (!resultarray[i].Contains(sub)) containsAllSubjects = false;
        }
        if (containsAllSubjects) count++;
    }
```

Now let me explain what this code is doing peace by peace:

```
    foreach(char sub in subjects)
```

With this *foreach-Loop* we get every character you've put into the *subjects* array. This is just a convenience to ensure the code even works if you'd change your subject characters.

```
    if(!resultarray[i].Contains(sub)) containsAllSubjects = false;
```

Because we're iterating with every single *sub* character from your subjects array over this expression we check whether the current string from the *resultarray* contains every single one of the subject characters. If one or more subject characters are missing in the current string, we set a boolean variable to false.

```
    if(containsAllSubjects) count++;
```

Since the boolean variable *containsAllSubjects* is only true when every single subject was inside the string we've checked we can increase the *count* by one.

---

Another thing I'd recommend is to change the separation of your *skills* string. The way you're doing it right now is to separate after 5 characters which is the correct way to do for you when your *subjects* array contains 5 elements. However, if you ever wanted to change the number of subjects you'd have to think of changing the hard-coded magic number 5 in your skills string separation, too. This is why I'd recommend separating according to the number of elements the subjects array contains:

```
    if (l % subjects.Length == 0 && l > 0)
    {
         sb.Append(" ");
    }
```

That way your code becomes flexible in regard of the number of subjects.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNb9swDL37V3AFVttI5/bSU5YCWa8dMCwBdghykGUmUafYnih364r89oySEid2Eqw8SDDFx4/3ZEn6JCuD221DqlzC5JUsrofR8Vf2pMpfPdcU/9hhJLUggm@mWhqxjoDtza/OyAqrJKjSwhTFOiFrHJ5@Kq0pbcMOAGdyJcxsDtTkzygtwQjeIBbxDcS5W2S8GXbiXXZZNbyO4O70qHbuG5BhW4ctD9vf85BCvSiqzOnhrjWD1GhXLgySTatHPhgbI16TtIuY@Im/NEoXaIBc3RJ/d90O0wHd3tbCEIJdIewosxXc@/IEKOSKW6i5CyytP@S4e45sCnbQnrmsm3TBAyVuOu3n4u3zvv8nLJd2xa7BIO1gusJ4ehaQaPjYqrPDwohzwvU1Z32Au/QEdprIX488G9c1lkVyBVc94pxtosuI0PpMz3u4TdQde8cfT78WXrKc5Qr097Vy9ALVQiLHxRAPzyRq1RdObY4LibNJrZVNPNipeZ55FZhXzPxRkpZ@9X/686rSfNlLK1RJY60nh5/EmgZPKeTa7r4kYbYm5/vdavdemZzmH44anql59rjrIeFkaXqhpYXQhO@R1VU4kyIN//Vg0Jf4@MugbUwZIg9xm6j/CL1UqoCvXCFplRRmefEV4gGp0pj9MMoiP36Y@Bds7/6OovDeND3cotDYZrsVuZQ5L0LkbEJK@Q8)

I hope my answer could help you at least somewhat with your question.